# Difference of free transform and inserting the font-size in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text

Is there any difference in free-transforming a text or just adding the bigger font size??

Answer (score 0):

Reading the question as it was written:

Free transform allows also stretching the proportions and rotation. But it is still editable text, as the following example shows:

[image]

**About scaling:**

There are many non-proportional settings which behave differently if you scale by transformation than by changing the font size. You find them from the Character- and Paragraph panels. An example:

[image]

The leftmost text is transformed to 75% size => all spacings are scaled, too. The rightmost has got 25% smaller font size => the spacing is now quite sparse, because they are given as points, not percents

NOTE: Fonts can have internal scaling rules which make bigger font sizes different than the same font in smaller point size, but enlargened. Photoshop seems to change the font size when a text object is scaled, but it needs some underhood knowledge to be sure, are the internal scaling rules of the font really honored. I haven't seen any differences.

Comment: Sometimes you need to read between the lines. To me it's quite clear that the thread starter asks whether there is any difference in the result, changing the font size using the font-size attribute or scaling the text proportionally (using transform).